# Image is not displayed in the table via ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table in which ngFor loops, all data is displayed as it should, but the picture is not, only its path. I understand that I myself put the path on the picture in a constant, but how do I do it correctly.

```
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
            <th class="security__table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              {{ column.header }}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              {{ column.cell(row) }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
```

[image]

I need the pictures to be displayed correctly

Comment: First of all, you're just displaying the string value, not an img tag (or icon tag, whatever  you planned to do) with that string as src. Second, it seems that your path will not work: keep images in assets folder, not the other way around - so instead of `img/assets/trash-icon.svg` you should have `assets/img/trash-icon.svg`

Comment: @MishaMashina I understand that img should be used but I don't understand how to integrate it and how, because of ngFor

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the HTML image tags `<img>` somewhere to display images.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
        <th class="security__table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          {{ column.header }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          {{ column.cell(row) }}
          <img *ngIf="column.columnDef == 'removeButton'" class="security__table-icon" src="assets/img/trash-icon.svg"/>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```